# Why is RemoveFontResourceW not working to remove a font in Python?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, fonts

I added a font resource file to my Tkinter GUI app using

```
gdi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('gdi32')
gdi32.AddFontResourceW(font_path)
```

It works great, however, I can't seem to remove the font from the user's system.

When the user exits the program, I want to **remove** the font resource using

```
gdi32.RemoveFontResourceW(font_path)
```

however, it does not seem to work at all. **What am I missing here?**

For reference, here is the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/font-installation-and-deletion#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Control%20Panel,application%20even%20before%20the%20reboot.) that explains the usage of the add/remove font functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`RemoveFontResourceW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-removefontresourcew) documentation:

> **If there are outstanding references to a font, the associated resource remains loaded until no device context is using it.** Furthermore, if the font is listed in the font registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`) and is installed to any location other than the `%windir%\fonts\` folder, it may be loaded into other active sessions (including session 0).

So, make sure there really are no more references to the font before you try to remove it.

Also, make sure you are broadcasting `WM_FONTCHANGE`, like the documentation says:

> We recommend that if an app adds or removes fonts from the system font table that it notify other windows of the change by sending a `WM_FONTCHANGE` message to all top-level windows in the system. The app sends this message by calling the `SendMessage` function with the `hwnd` parameter set to `HWND_BROADCAST`.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, I think the issue was that something was still somehow using the font file which is why it wasn't being removed. Restarting my PC and calling a remove after each load did the job. The font gets successfully removed.